# What is a concurrent language?

Tags: java

From the Java Language Specification:

> The Java™ programming language is a general-purpose, concurrent, class-based,
>   object-oriented language.

What is a concurrent language?

Comment: One that exists at the same time as other languages?

Comment: @Neil: Wouldn't "concurrent" mean it takes turns existing with other languages? :)

Comment: A Clean Congruent Rug (http://wordsmith.org/anagram/anagram.cgi?anagram=concurrent+language&t=1000&a=n)

Comment: Concurrency is the idea that code can run simultaneous to other code, rather than the old paradigm of reading down a list of instructions in order.  Java supports this at the level of the language instead of with libraries.

Comment: I love how stackoverflow is able to contribute so much to the careers of budding, young comedians.

Comment: @dnh828: You're mostly correct but 'simultaneous' is a poor choice of words here given that the term 'concurrency' in this instance is specifically chosen because it doesn't mean 'at the same time'.

Answer (score 15):

It means that threads and synchronization are built into the language, rather than being part of a library that you may include (like PThreads for C).

Answer (score 5):

Designed with [concurrent computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing) in mind.

Answer (score 5):

It's a language optimized, or at least thought to be used for concurrent computing. It will have built in simplifications to handle things as threads.

> Concurrent computing is a form of
>   computing in which programs are
>   designed as collections of interacting
>   computational processes that may be
>   executed in parallel.

[via wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing)

You can simply make a method synchronized because Java is a concurrent language. Like the doc says :

> To make a method synchronized, simply
>   add the synchronized keyword to its
>   declaration:

```
public class SynchronizedCounter {
    private int c = 0;

    public synchronized void increment() {
        c++;
    }

    public synchronized void decrement() {
        c--;
    }

    public synchronized int value() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

[via](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

Comment: I would say that "You can simply make a method synchronized because Java is a concurrent language" and not the other way around

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like marketing waffle ... almost no one I know would regard any language to be "concurrent" just because it has a few primitives or syntactic sugar around threading and locking.

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) if you want to know more about concurrency and java